# Building navigation structure in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm making my little project app and I have some problem.

My navigatino structure is like below.

Drawer Navigator ---- Bottom Tab Navigator

```
                                       ---- HOME (gesture enable)                   
                                       ---- SETTING (gesture disable)
                                       ---- OTHERS (gesture disable)
```

I'd like to make this, but I don't know how to do this.

Is there any tip of doing this??

Answer (score 0):

React navigation docs is a good place to start https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started. More directly look into stack navigation then drawer navigation and tab navigation. Essentially the stack will allow you to add other navigation elements to your app.

---